# "HTTP Status 404 -" When launching REST API on server

Tags: json, apache, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am rather new to using REST APIs and I'm just trying for now to launch a simple Hello world application on the server.

The Tomcat server is running fine and it is configured on the 8082 port. When I run the localhost:8082, the main page opens normally.

I have created a project called "IGEHOTELSERVER" with a package "HelloWorld" in which I have included the following class:

```
package HelloWorld;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 public String sayPlainTextHello() {
     return "Hello World";
 }

}
```

Below is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>IGEHOTELSERVER</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>HelloWorld</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
         </init-param>

         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

To launch a test: Right-click on the class -> Run as -> Run on the server.
A browser then opens with the following URL:
http://localhost:8082/IGEHOTELSERVER/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorld/Hello.java

Here's what I get:
HTTP Status 404 - 
type Status report
description The requested resource is not available

I have already tried switching the location to the Tomcat server location in the server properties as well as enabling "Use Tomcat installation" but the problem persists.

Can anyone please suggest a possible solution?

Comment: *when I run the class on the server*: what does that mean? Which URL do you use to "run this class on the server"?

Comment: And if your package is named "HelloWorld", why do you set the jersey.config.server.provider.packages property to IGEHOTELSERVER?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the URL. I have also tried replacing the project name with the package name for the jersey.config.server.provider.packages property but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use *Right-click on the class -> Run as -> Run on the server*: your IDE is not smart enough to analyze the whole servlet + Jersey configuration and use the right URL. Open your browser and enter the correct URL. Your Jersey resource is mapped to /hello. Jersey is mapped to /rest/* inside your app. Your app is mapped to /IGEHOTELSERVER. I don't use Jersey, but my guess would thus be that the correct path should be /IGEHOTELSERVER/rest/hello. But you should of course read the documentation instead of trying random things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have also tried this and it doesn't work.